# error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1900' doesn't match value '1600'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking

I have tried to use a static library compiled with vc14 into my project compiled with vc10.
I got this error : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1900' doesn't match value '1600'.
I know that : Static libraries must be built with the same compiler version

Is there any way to solve this issue other than recompile my project with vc14 ?
Any suggestion ?

Comment: _"I know that : Static libraries must be built with the same compiler version"_ So you just answered your question yourself? There's no way other than recompiling the complete code, which should be statically linked.

Comment: I think they were hoping for some alternate solution however attempting to link binaries made from incompatible compilers, with incompatible standard library implementations is not going to end well.

Comment: Does recompiling the library with VC10 count as an alternative?

Comment: @JaMiT unfortunately the library is external, there is no version in vc10

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the library is external, there is no version in vc10, I am looking for another alternate solution :(

Comment: @MeGoo what's the problem to compile your code with vc14 as well?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just customer's requirement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One principle of using static libraries is "downward compatibility", but because VS defaults to open /GL, if you do not close it, this will cause the compiled static library to greatly reduce the compatibility. In order to ensure the compatibility of lib files, I suggest trying to turn off /GL in the static library project. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170) for details.